# UWP Grid Splitter always stick to mouse

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

**The issue is continued in WindowsCommunityToolkit repo:**
https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3949

**TL;DR** - See bold text in description.

As seen in the gif below, the mouse/cursor is on the grid splitter until the grid-splitter collides/stops. The mouse/cursor will continue to move outside, which is correct. Now, when I move the mouse back, the grid-splitter is moving without having the cursor fixed to it (the grid splitter is based on mouse movement and not mouse position). **So, what I want is for the cursor/mouse to always be on the grid-splitter when is moving.**

[image: gif showing that mouse don't always stick to the mouse]

```xml
<Grid>
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="39"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <controls:GridSplitter
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Width="2"
        ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment"
        ResizeDirection="Auto"
    ></controls:GridSplitter>
    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what I want is for the cursor/mouse to always be on the grid-splitter when is moving.

We could reproduce this with Community ToolKit Gallery app, We suggest you post this issue in toolkit github [issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues) box. And currently there is not good workaround for this. To make sure cursor will not offset, please move the splitter slowly.

Comment: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3949